# Can we use Authy to send custom verification code in SMS and in Email?

Tags: twilio, authy

We've our own solution for code generation and we want to send the code generated by us through Authy. Is that possible to send custom verification code using Authy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Verify supports this (along with Voice, SMS, and Email channels).

[Custom Verification Codes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/customization-options#custom-verification-codes)